# Fixing duplicates in Excel by Concatenating another field to the duplicate

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have information similar to the following in and large excel file:

```
Name            ZipCode
ABC Pharmacy    32566-3456
ABC Pharmacy    32502-2345
....            ....
```

The excel file is over 2000 entries long and several duplicates exist in the Name field which will eventually be a key field in the database where this data will end up. These aren't really duplicates, just businesses with the same name (like a franchise). In order to eliminate the duplicates I would like to append the unique Zip Code to the pharmacy name for all duplicates (but only for duplicates) so that I end up with this:

```
Name                        ZipCode
ABC Pharmacy-32566-3456     32566-3456
ABC Pharmacy-32502-2345     32502-2345
....            ....
```

Can I do this with formulas?

Comment: If your existing data is in say column A and column B and you want your adjusted data to also be in column A and column B, you will need to use VBA or a built in function.  Formulas can only place results in new cells.

Comment: Assuming you are placing the concatenated list in column C, what do you want placed in column C for unique entries?

Comment: A new column is OK. In that case, `Column C` should be either `Column A` or (in case of duplicate) `Column A+Column B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below formula in `Column C`,

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,A1&"-"&B1,A1)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked great! Thanks! For some reason I had to start a new excel file and just paste in the values from the old file, but that did it! Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

You might need a helper column for that. Define one column (in my case D) with the formula (with A being the column with the name)

=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$2000;A2)>1

Then you can define a second helper column (for example column E) with the formula:

=IF(D2;CONCAT(A2;B2);A2)

This concatenates column B to column A if there are duplicate values.

Comment: I don't want to remove anything. I want to concatenate two fields ONLY IF the first field is a duplicate. Does that make sense?